# Sending JSON payload size and data over socket

Tags: python, sockets, byte

I've only ever sent strings over Python sockets and now I want to try and send JSON data over, that also informs the other side the size of the data (payload). For the payload header, I want it to be 4 bytes, even if the size doesn't precede the first byte, this would be 00.

Example: Decimal 1010 --> Hex 0x03f2, thus payload header would be 00 00 03 f2

**In the case of endianess**

Before posting, I realized this might be a question. I was thinking network byte order, being **Big Endian**.

So far I have

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import os
import struct
import sys
import time

from io import BytesIO
from threading import Thread

import socket

server_ip = 'localhost'
server_port = 1337

def server_thread():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((server_ip, server_port))
    server_socket.listen(1)

    client_sock, address = server_socket.accept()
    print('Accepted connection from {}:{}'.format(address[0], address[1]))

    while client_sock:
        request = client_sock.recv(8192)
        if not request:
            break
        fd = open('payload.data', 'w')
        fd.write(request)
        fd.flush()
        fd.close()

    print('Closing server')

server = Thread(target=server_thread)
server.start()

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((server_ip, server_port))

# Convert
data = json.load(open('data.json', 'r'))
try: 

    data_size = (len(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')))

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

client_socket.send(json.dumps(data))
client_socket.close()
```

I've used struct in the past but is it possible to pack the payload header, json data all into one?

Thanks! The data.json is arbitrary, make whatever you want. I used

```
{
    "data" : "I love data."
}
```

**Updates**

Since this may be a strange question or difficult, idk? I'll post my progress.

**This converts the data into Big Endian and has the two bytes, now I just need the third. The string is also just one place, though I thought it'd be an array from documentation.**

```
fmt = '>Hs'
struct_data = struct.pack(fmt, data_size, json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: I would use struct only to send size and rest send as bytes  - `json.dumps(data).encoded('utf-8')`. I even do this in example [simple protocol](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/socket)

Comment: **I've only ever sent strings over Python sockets** JSON *is* a string.

Comment: That's the whole point -- JSON is a way of converting structured data to a string, so you can send it easily.

Comment: @Barmar I'm aware of JSON being a string, the payload is what I'm after, thus not entirely a string but bytes followed by a string.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging with Python's Struct module, I finally arrived at an answer.

Originally I wanted to have a payload header of 3-bytes but I later changed to 4-bytes to accommodate my answer.

```
try: 

    data_size = (len(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')))
    struct_data = struct.pack('!I', data_size) + json.dumps(data)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

- ! Indicates network byte ordering, being Big Endian
- I Indicates an unsigned int

I then tagged the string afterwards.

Overall, the data has looks like

- 00 01 38 80  7B 22 6D 73  67 22 3A 20...

The first 4 bytes is the payload size and following is the JSON string.